# Regular Expression - Extract Word in r

Tags: r, regex

how can I extract MLA723950998 from this string?

"https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-723950998-peugeot-208-0km-16-active-plan-100-financiado-darc-_JM"

I was able to manage to extract MLA.

```
gsub('.*(M\\w+).*', '\\1', "https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-723950998-peugeot-208-0km-16-active-plan-100-financiado-darc-_JM")
```

MLA

Comment: Try `gsub('.*/(M\\w+)-(\\d+).*', '\\1\\2', "https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-723950998-peugeot-208-0km-16-active-plan-100-financiado-darc-_JM")`

Comment: Excellent!! works ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
.*/(M\w+)-(\d+).*
```

and replace with `\1\2`.

**Details**

- `.*/` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible, up to and including the last `/` in the string
- `(M\w+)` - Group 1 (later referred to with `\1` placeholder from the replacement pattern): `M` and 1+ letters, digits or/and `_`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(\d+)` - Group 2 (later referred to with `\2` placeholder from the replacement pattern): one or more digits
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qz3EFb/1)

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/HlmZaR):

```
x <- "https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-723950998-peugeot-208-0km-16-active-plan-100-financiado-darc-_JM"
gsub('.*/(M\\w+)-(\\d+).*', '\\1\\2', x)
# => [1] "MLA723950998"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution works for you:

```
library(stringi)
x = "https://auto.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-723950998-peugeot-208-0km-16-active-plan-100-financiado-darc-_JM"
stri_extract_last_regex(x, "(?<=/)([A-Za-z]+.\\d+)(?=[^/]+$)")
[1] "MLA-723950998"
```

(i) The first lookbehind finds the position of a slash, (ii) which is then followed by letters, 1 x any character and digits, (iii) which by the lookahead may only be followed by anything but a slash.